# How to reduce audio file size in Javascript

Tags: node.js, reactjs, audio

I'm trying to reduce audio file size I get in frontend(React), and sending it to AWS S3 by nodeJS.

Is there any function or Node Package I can use?

Comment: have you already tried something by yourself?

Comment: Do you mean lossy audio compression? Which format do you use for original files?